# jQuery extension method to serialize select elements as dictionaries

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form>
    <input name="foo" value="1" />

    <input name="bar[1]" value="a" />
    <input name="bar[2]" value="b" />
    <input name="bar[3]" value="c" />

    <select name="test" multiple>
        <option value="1" selected>a</option>
        <option value="2" selected>b</option>
        <option value="3" selected>c</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I can serialize the form like this:

```
$('form').serialize();
```

Which produces:

```
"foo=1&bar%5B1%5D=a&bar%5B2%5D=b&bar%5B3%5D=c&test=1&test=2&test=3"
```

I would like to serialize the select elements as dictionaries, producing this instead:

```
"foo=1&bar%5B1%5D=a&bar%5B2%5D=b&bar%5B3%5D=c&test%5B1%5D=a&test%5B2%5D=b&test%5B3%5D=c"
```

This is what I have so far:

```
function serializeSelectListAsDictionary() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name'),
        obj = {};

    if (!$(this).is('select') || !name) {
        return '';
    }

    $(this).children('option:selected').each(function() {
        var key = name + '[' + $(this).val() + ']',
            value = $(this).html();

        obj[key] = value;
    });

    return $.param(obj);
}

$.fn.serializeDictionary = function() {
    var serialized;

    if (this.is('select')) {
        return serializeSelectListAsDictionary.apply(this);
    }

    serialized = this.serialize();

    this.find('select').each(function() {
        serialized = serialized.replace($(this).serialize(), serializeSelectListAsDictionary.apply(this));
    });

    return serialized;
};
```

This works well enough when I call it like this:

```
$('form').serializeDictionary();
```

But a problem arises when I try to select multiple elements. Say I added another select element to the form:

```
<form>
    <input name="foo" value="1" />

    <input name="bar[1]" value="a" />
    <input name="bar[2]" value="b" />
    <input name="bar[3]" value="c" />

    <select name="test" multiple>
        <option value="1" selected>a</option>
        <option value="2" selected>b</option>
        <option value="3" selected>c</option>
    </select>

    <select name="blah" multiple>
        <option value="4" selected>d</option>
        <option value="5" selected>e</option>
        <option value="6" selected>f</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Then if I call my extension method like this:

```
$('select').serializeDictionary();
```

It produces:

```
"test%5B1%5D=a&test%5B2%5D=b&test%5B3%5D=c&test%5B4%5D=d&test%5B5%5D=e&test%5B6%5D=f"
```

The output should look like this:

```
"test%5B1%5D=a&test%5B2%5D=b&test%5B3%5D=c&blah%5B4%5D=d&blah%5B5%5D=e&blah%5B6%5D=f"
```

I think my `serializeSelectListAsDictionary` function is only being called on the first element, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t5aze4r9/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the `serializeDictionary` function. It assumes that it will only receive one element to serialize. It works in the case of `$('form').serializeDictionary();` because it only matches one `form` element. But if you had two `form` you'll see the same issue as with `$('select').serializeDictionary();`.

The issue shows up when the selector is matching more than one element because you are only serializing the first one. You need some kind of iteration over the matched elements.

Here is a proposal that tries to keep as much as possible your code structure:

```
$.fn.serializeDictionary = function() {
    var serialized = this.serialize();

    // Here is the key! You need to iterate over all the matched elements.
    this.each(function() {
        if ($(this).is('select')) {
            serialized = serialized.replace($(this).serialize(), serializeSelectListAsDictionary.apply(this));
        } else {         
            $(this).find('select').each(function() {
                serialized = serialized.replace($(this).serialize(), serializeSelectListAsDictionary.apply(this));
            });
        } 
    });

    return serialized;
};
```

See [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/t5aze4r9/2/).